# New York Yankees logo

Tags: baseball, mlb

There seems to be 2 logos for New York Yankees. The rightmost one seems to be the official one. How about the leftmost one?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are.

The left logo is the official team logo since 1968.

The right one with the letters NY is the more famous one, because it's way older and they still use it on the caps and jerseys. This iconic logo has been introduced in 1915 and was the official brand logo until 1946 and has been used on the team wear ever since.

In 1947 the Yankees introduced a logo very similar to the left one.

Sources:

- [Worldsportslogos.com](https://worldsportlogos.com/new-york-yankees-logo/)
- [Sportslogos.net](https://www.sportslogos.net/logos/list_by_team/68/New_York_Yankees/)

Comment: The old NY logo also has the advantage from a design perspective of being one color, and a simpler design more easily recognized from a distance or at small scale, hence its continued use on hats and jerseys.

Comment: Side question: how long has the logo on the right been referred to as the "interlocking NY"?  I first heard Michael Kay use it when he did color commentary for Yankees games on the radio in the early 2000s.  I've always been curious because it's a misnomer—neither letter has a hole so they can't interlock.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang the logo from 1905 was referred to as interlocking NY as well, but I don't know when or who called it first.